# Update layout after writing SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, layout, refresh

My first thread here - sorry if the text formatting is bad.

I use Android Studio 3.1.3 API27 and work on an app for Smartphone.

The app currently consists of 1 activity (split in 3 fragments), a second activity and 5 xml files.

By using a ViewPager, I'm able to swipe through the 3 fragments.

The 2nd fragment (middle fragment) contains 2 buttons that each open the 2nd activity, which contains many color buttons.

When clicking on the color buttons, I can change the background colors of the 1st fragment.

After choosing a color, the 2nd activity gets closed and I'm back in activity 1 -> fragment2.

It works, **but the PROBLEM is that I always have to swipe to the 3rd fragment,
then back to the 2nd and then to the 1st.**

**If I don't do this, the colors of fragment 1 will remain the old ones.**

Now I'm looking for a way to update the layout of fragment 1 as soon as I press a color button of activity 2.

I already tried this:

- when writing the SharedPreferences (Activity2), I use editor.apply() instead of editor.commit()
- when reading the SharedPreferences (Activity1 -> Fragment1), I use Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS instead of Context.MODE_PRIVATE
- using viewpage.setOffscreenPageLimit(0); in the MainActivity inside of my public void SetUpViewPager(ViewPager viewpage) method.

Nothing helped, though.

**This is how it looks like:**

[image: This is how it looks like (GIF-Animation):]

MainActivity.java (Activity 1):

```
import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
    import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    {
        ViewPager vp;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            ViewPager vp = findViewById(R.id.vp);
            SetUpViewPager(vp);
        }
        public void SetUpViewPager(ViewPager viewpage)
        {
            MyViewPagerAdapter Adapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            Adapter.AddPageFragment(new Page_1(), "Page 1");
            Adapter.AddPageFragment(new Page_2(), "Page 2");
            Adapter.AddPageFragment(new Page_3(), "Page 3");
            viewpage.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
            viewpage.setAdapter(Adapter);
        }
        public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter
        {
            private List<Fragment> MyFragment = new ArrayList<>();
            private List<String> MyPageTitle = new ArrayList<>();

            public MyViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager)
            {
                super(manager);
            }
            public void AddPageFragment(Fragment Frag, String Title)
            {
                MyFragment.add(Frag);
                MyPageTitle.add(Title);
            }
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int i)
            {
                return MyFragment.get(i);
            }

            @Nullable
            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)
            {
                return MyPageTitle.get(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount()
            {
                return 3;
            }
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            int id = item.getItemId();

            if (id == R.id.action_settings)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Page_1.java (Activity 1 -> Fragment 1):

```
import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

    public class Page_1 extends Fragment
    {
        int backgroundColorLeft, backgroundColorRight, textColorLeft, textColorRight; // Variables for SharedPreferences

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View PageOne = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page1, container, false); // Link view to layout?
            return PageOne;
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("bgColor", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS); // Load saved shared file
            backgroundColorLeft = prefs.getInt("backgroundColorLeft", backgroundColorLeft); // Load saved background color for left layout
            textColorLeft = prefs.getInt("textColorLeft", textColorLeft); // Load saved text color for left layout
            backgroundColorRight = prefs.getInt("backgroundColorRight", backgroundColorRight); // Load saved background color for right layout
            textColorRight = prefs.getInt("textColorRight", textColorRight); // Load saved text color for right layout

            RelativeLayout relLayoutLeft = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rel_layout_left); // Link variable to ID of left layout
            relLayoutLeft.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColorLeft); // Change background color of left layout
            TextView tvLeft = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_left); // Link variable to ID
            tvLeft.setTextColor(textColorLeft); // Change text color of left layout

            RelativeLayout relLayoutRight = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.rel_layout_right); // Link variable to ID of right layout
            relLayoutRight.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColorRight); // Change background color of right layout
            TextView tvRight = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tv_right); // Link variable to ID
            tvRight.setTextColor(textColorRight); // Change text color of right layout
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        }
    }
```

Page_2.java (Activity 1 -> Fragment 2):

```
package com.example.konstantin.clipcodes_swiping;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

    import static android.content.Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

    public class Page_2 extends Fragment
    {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View PageTwo = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2, container, false);
            Button buttonLeft = PageTwo.findViewById(R.id.button_left);  // Link variable to ID of left button
            buttonLeft.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int pos = 1; // Set position to left
                    setPosition(pos); // Load setColor method and send 2 color values
                }
            });
            Button buttonRight = PageTwo.findViewById(R.id.button_right);  // Link variable to ID of right button
            buttonRight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    int pos = 2; // Set position to right
                    setPosition(pos); // Load setColor method and send 2 color values
                }
            });
            return PageTwo;
        }
        public void setPosition (int pos) // Start second activity to choose colors
        {
            Intent intentPos = new Intent(getActivity(), Page_4_Colors.class); // Create intent for current Activity and target activity
            SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("bgColor", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS); // Create new SharedPreferences instance
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); // Assign variable to editor function
            editor.putInt("position", pos); // Write selected position (int) inside of editor
            editor.apply(); // Save values, close process
            getActivity().startActivity(intentPos); // Start second activity
        }
    }
```

Page_3.java (Activity 1 -> Fragment 3):

```
        import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;

    public class Page_3 extends Fragment
    {
        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View PageThree = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page3, container, false);
            return PageThree;
        }
    }
```

Page_4_Colors.java (Activity 2):

```
        import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.SharedPreferences;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;

    public class Page_4_Colors extends Activity
    {
        int pos;
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.page4_colors);
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("bgColor", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS); // Load saved shared file
            pos = prefs.getInt("position", pos); // Load saved position (int)
            Log.wtf("Position", String.valueOf(pos)); // Show pos value in Log
            Button buttonWhite = findViewById(R.id.button_white);
            buttonWhite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); // Load setColor method and send 2 color values
                }
            });
            Button buttonYellow = findViewById(R.id.button_yellow);
            buttonYellow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.yellow), getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); // Load setColor method and send 2 color values
                }
            });
            Button buttonOrange = findViewById(R.id.button_orange);
            buttonOrange.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.orange), getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); // Load setColor method and send 2 color values
                }
            });
            Button buttonRed = findViewById(R.id.button_red);
            buttonRed.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red), getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); // Load setColor method and send 2 color values
                }
            });
            Button buttonGreen = findViewById(R.id.button_green);
            buttonGreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green), getResources().getColor(R.color.black)); // Load setColor method and send 2 color values
                }
            });
            Button buttonBlue = findViewById(R.id.button_blue);
            buttonBlue.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue), getResources().getColor(R.color.white)); // Load setColor method and send 2 color values
                }
            });
        }
        public void setColor (int backgroundColor, int textColor) // Write color values into SharedPreferences
        {
            SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("bgColor", MODE_MULTI_PROCESS); // Create new SharedPreferences instance
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit(); // Assign variable to editor function
            if (pos == 1)
            {
                editor.putInt("backgroundColorLeft", backgroundColor); // Write background color (int) inside of editor
                editor.putInt("textColorLeft", textColor); // Write text color (int) inside of editor
            }
            if (pos == 2)
            {
                editor.putInt("backgroundColorRight", backgroundColor); // Write background color (int) inside of editor
                editor.putInt("textColorRight", textColor); // Write text color (int) inside of editor
            }
            editor.apply(); // Save values, close process
            this.finish(); // Close this activity
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: so you want to update color directly when you change it?

Comment: in first fragment which you had written in onActivityCreated cut paste in onResume()

Comment: Sorry @VishalThakkar, I didn't read your reply when I wrote my answer.

Comment: Oh, wow, that actually solved it! Thanks! Do I even need the onActivityCreated?

Answer (score 0):

You can update the UI (or at least the color related part) for each fragment in the onResume() method, thus, when you return from the second activity, it will refresh.

Comment: Thanks. I assume in this case I should add onResume inside of Page_2.java? So each time I close Acitivity 2 (and go back to Page_2 automatically), it will execute the onResume method. I made a test with: Log.wtf("test", "Fragment2 loaded"); and yes, it worked. But, I don't know exactly what I have to post inside of this method.

Comment: what you wrote in onActivityCreated, like @Vishal Thakkar said

Answer (score 0):

use [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)

unregister and register EventBus in Page_1 `onStop()` and `onStart()`

```
 EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)

 EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
```

and use this for post the value

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("Change Color"));
```

and this function will handle the MessageEvent

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {
    //change the color here
    //add this function in Page_1 
}
```

when you update the value of color. put in MessageEvent [documentation](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/)

Answer (score 0):

When a Fragment is made visible (i.e., the selected page in your ViewPager), its setUserVisibleHint() method is called. You can override that method in your Fragment and use it to trigger a refresh.

```
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if(isVisibleToUser){
         //you can check if the color is changed then refresh the fragment if not then don't do anything
         //here you should refresh your fragment , this will called every time you
         //view this fragment in all cases even if you didn't move to the 
         //third tab 
        }
    }
```

**How To Refresh A Fragment**

```
    Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("YourFragmentTag");
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: this works, however the method will be called when the viewpager finished scrolling. So he will see the old color until the scrolling is done, and then change the color :)

Comment: this method will be called every time he goes to the fragment even if he was in the second tab and then moved to first or third to first , so no he will not see the old color try to implement it....what I mean that this method will be called every time he visit the fragment no matter he finished scrolling or not or where he is (with respect to tab postion like second third)

Comment: You are correct. But he shouldn't put the code in if(isVisibleToUser) that will be called only when the fragment is visible.

Comment: you're right ! a good point , but  he can do a simple check, like if the color has changed then refresh if not then don't do anything

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Ok, I tried it but had no success yet. I created a public static final String PAGE_1_FRAGMENT = "page_1_fragment"; inside of my Page_1.java and added the public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) inside of it. Then I added your "how to refresh a fragment" code and changed "YourFragmentTag" by PAGE_1_FRAGMENT. I also tried "page_1_fragment", which didn't work. The app crashes as soon as I start it.

Comment: you should add the tag in a different way not like this